# 12 VDC LED noise

Tags: led

I have a place off grid with a 12 VDC system. I have been changing out all of my lights with 1 and 2 watt 12 volt LEDs. The problem I'm running into is the noise coming through the stereo speakers. I have some 1 pair shielded wire I may try, but I don't want to re-wire if I don't have to. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of noise are you talking about? Do you have an inverter providing AC? Is that how you power your amp? Also this question might be more suitable on http://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Strictly DC, no inverter. A high pitched noise that blocks out FM radio stations and makes some background noise through the speakers if an iPod or something similar. I get the noise also from 12 volt chargers.

Comment: Then Autistic's answer is correct. There's SMPS noise from both of those sources (matching the frequencies you describe) and audio amps are quite susceptible to them. Typically "hifi" audio amps run from linear (non switched) supplies for that reason. It's actually quite hard to get rid of the HF noise once it's in. Most linear voltage regulators are optimized for blocking mains-frequency noise... and filters of SMPS ones don't block enough noise. SMPS noise injection works in both directions. Yours probably have poor (or non-existent) filters toward "in". Open one up an perhaps post an image.

Answer (score 1):

The convertors that supply the LEDs are switchmode and are making lots of noise .You can use linear instead with a loss of efficiency .You could buy better more expensive convertor .You could start to filter the wiring first at the Led fitting .If things are still bad then shielded cable will help .

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use suitable capacitor on the out of your VDC point. But I don't know your circuit, you need to find best uF value to use.

Don't forget to add cooler metal for your transistors. Also check them whether they are in true working area or not.

Also coil and capacitor resonance is a point for your circuit to get clear voice.

Don't forget to get equal ohm value from your circuit to out point to the laud speaker's ohm value. If yours is 8ohm, your circuit should out 8ohm total resistor value.